# Pegar html de uma tag, incluindo a própria tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Como eu pegaria uma parte do meu html junto com as tags? Por exemplo:

[image: duvida]

Queria pegar esse span dentro do TD, no caso eu queria com tudo junto, até a tag `<span>`, sacou?

Answer (score 2):

Com JavaScript puro, basta pegar o [`outerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Element/outerHTML) do elemento. Por exemplo, para esse seu span:

```js
var span = document.querySelector('#play1_3_2');
var html = span.outerHTML;
console.log(html);
```

```html
<span id="play1_3_2"></span>
```

Comment: O que seria o `outerHTML`?

Comment: O `outerHTML` é o `innerHTML` + a própria tag (incluindo atributos).